# Segmentation Fault data type

Tags: c++, types, segmentation-fault

I was trying to get a mathematical result but I kept on getting a segmentation fault, the segmentation fault occurs at the "cout" line. I don't think anything is wrong in the r[] array or the LJ[] array.

```
   for (k = 0; k < 15; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            if (i == k)
            {
                NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                //Use the 3D distance formula
                term1 = fabs(x[k] - x[i]);
                term1 = pow(term1, 2);
                term2 = fabs(y[k] - z[i]);
                term2 = pow(term2, 2);
                term3 = fabs(z[k] - z[i]);
                term3 = pow(term3, 2);
                result = term1 + term2 + term3;
                result = sqrt(result);
                r[h] = result;                      //Store the result in an array
                h++;
            }
        }
    }




    //Calculate Lennard-Jones potential of every pair
    for(itr = 0; itr < 210; itr++)
    {
        term1 = pow(r[itr], 12);
        term1 = 1/term1;
        term2 = pow(r[itr], 6);
        term2 = 2/term2;
        LJ[itr] = term1 - term2;
    }

    double Ei;

    for(itr = 0; itr < 210; itr++)
    {
        Ei = LJ[itr] + Ei;
    }
    Ei = Ei/2;
    cout << "The new Energy level " << Ei << endl;
```

Comment: The seg-fault is not in the `cout` line for sure (unless you have done something really, really bad with `cout`, which I can't imagine :D). How is `LJ` defined?

Comment: Then there's something else. Paste more code.

Comment: May be `double Ei;` is not properly initialized? => `double Ei = 0`;

Comment: @DracoAter - this would print garbage, but will not cause seg-fault.

Comment: Try using the highest warning level of your compiler (which one is it?) it could help to identify suspicious looking code.

Comment: Don't you have some typo here: `term2 = fabs(y[k] - z[i]);` - Shouldn't be `y` instead of `z`?

Comment: I hope `r` has at least 225 elements, because you are increasing `h` each time in a `15*15` loop, which is `225`.

Comment: @hochl no because he is increasing only when i != k so he hopes to calculate only off diagonal elements. But it is always tricky to compute the boundaries right, so it's better to avoid having to ...

Comment: Oh, right you are. Now the whole thing looks somewhat off, what is this `NULL;` supposed to do?

Comment: So r[] is supposed to hold the distance from one particle to another (there are 16 in total)...since i dont want to calculate the distance from itself i put the NULL there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: you have updated the definition of LJ, so this is no longer the issue.
Since this is c++, why are you using loop and indexing? a better (as in: a safer) solution would be to use the standard library algorithms and in particular [accumulate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aawk6wsh.aspx). 
By doing this you would *gain in clarity* and *possibly remove* the source of the segfault.

Unless other requirements are constraining you, you should follow Scott Meyer's [advice](http://drdobbs.com/184401446) of favoring algorithms over loops.

**Second Update, with the whole code available**: You must make sure that you are only accessing memory locations which you correctly allocated. So:

1. make sure that h is initialized at zero and
2. that you are never writing to r[210] and higher.

Better yet, remove all those magic numbers, instead of 210 use k_max * (j_max - 1) and define

```
const unsigned int k_max = 15;
const unsigned int j_max = 15;
```

Use a std::vector instead of an array, this will take care of memory allocation for you.

Printing the values of h and itr (or using a debugger, which is a very useful tool) will show you where you are accessing memory which you didn't reserve.

Comment: Ok and check out accumulate too because the issue was probably that you were computing one too many or one too few elements in the first loop. So: sidestep loops (or be doubly sure that you got the boundaries correct).

Comment: just a question, when I "push_back", do I have to specify where to push from, because for some reason when i declared LJ as a vector of 210, it starts pushing from 210 to 211 to 212 and so on

Comment: Also when using a vector use at() instead of operator[] to check the bounds of the vector. Esp. now while you are debugging. If the bounds check turns out too expensive you can remove it later.

Comment: if you construct the vector like std::vector<double> v(210) you are constructing a vector of 210 null initialized doubles. So push_back will start adding from 211 onward. You could do: std::vector<double> v; v.reserve(210); and then push_back your items..

Comment: do you know why i would get 0 when i do this: Ei = accumulate(LJ.begin(), LJ.end(), 0);

Comment: are you sure about what LJ contains? if it's always zero the sum will be zero. Check with some test code that every function you are writing works properly.

Comment: yeah, the LJ has proper values (non-zero)

Comment: Then it should work. Try a simpler program, inserting known values in the Lj vector. Look at this example: int main(){
const unsigned int N = 1000;
vector<unsigned int> v;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i <N; ++i) v.push_back(i);
int result(accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0));
if (result != (N*(N-1))/2) throw result;
return 0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a memory corruption in line

```
Ei = LJ[itr] + Ei;
```

Which generate the segfault later when execution of cout get a place.

Comment: @Josh - it's not the adding, it's the access to `LJ[itr]`.

Comment: Memory corruption in this case is int LJ[itr] and not in execution of + operator. So I guess that your write your data outside of LJ array.